# PHP Reading from a CSV file When Containing HTML Data

Tags: php, html, csv, tags, fgetcsv

I want to read from a `.csv` file that is separated by `semicolons(;)` and text delimiter is `double quotes(")`.

The problem is that the file has 2 fields that contain long HTML data which includes double quotes. When I open it in Excel, it's displayed correctly; however, when using the `fgetcsv($file, 0, ";"))` function, it gives me a messy data due to the double quotes in the HTML code.

Here's what I tried:

```
$file = fopen($file, "r");
if ($file) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ";")) !== false) {
        if (empty($header)) {
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
            $array[$header[$key]] = $value;  
        }       
        print_r($array);
    }

}
```

Just a note to those that will suggest me to use `strip_tags` function: I can't o that as I need the HTML content of the data. Besides, I'm not able to change how the data is put in the CSV, I can just read it.

Can someone helps me in overcoming this issue?

Comment: Could you give us some code? What have you tried so far? Could you post an example of your csv?

Comment: You'll probably need to read the file in line by line and parse it yourself.  It's just not valid to use the delimiters in the field values, so something like `fgetcsv` won't handle it.